# After the following code runs, how do I clear the user declared variable empName before the program runs again?

Tags: c++

The following program I created takes an array of type *string* whose values consist of employee names which are then sorted by the function sortArray().

After this it asks the user for an employee name to see if its in the array.

The name is searched for and the output tells the user what position the name is in the original array if found or if the is not found, it tells the user that the name wasn't found.

Lastly, I have a if, then statement to ask the user if they want to rerun the program so they can search for another name if they wish.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string> 
using namespace std;

//Function prototype
void sortArray(string[], int);
int binarySearch(string[], int, string);
const int SIZE = 20;
char input;

int main()
{
    //Program Description
    cout << "This program asks for a name, sorts the list, searches for a match in the list,\nand lastly outputs whether there is a match and the position in the array it is found.\n\n";

    //Defined array 
    const int NUM_NAMES = 20;
    string names[NUM_NAMES] = {"Collins, Bill", "Smith, Bart", "Allen, Jim", "Griffin, Jim", "Stamey, Marty", "Rose, Geri", "Taylor, Terri", "Johnson, Jill", "Allison, Jeff", "Looney, Joe", "Wolfe, Bill", "James, Jean", "Weaver, Jim", "Pore, Bob", "Rutherford, Greg", "Javens, Renee", "Harrison, Rose", "Setzer, Cathy", "Pike, Gordon", "Holland, Beth" };

    //Variables
    string empName;
    int results;

    //Sort array first
    sortArray(names, NUM_NAMES);

    //Prompt for user input to enter an employee name 
    cout << "Please enter an employee's name (last name, first name): ";
    getline(cin, empName);

    //Search for name
    results = binarySearch(names, NUM_NAMES, empName);

    //If results contains -1 the name was not found.
    if (results == -1)
        cout << "\nThat name does not exist in the array.\n";

    else
    {
        //Otherwise results contains the subscript of the specified employee ID in the array.
        cout << "\nThat name is found at element " << results;
        cout << " in the array.\n\n";
    }

    std::cout << "\nAre you sure you want to quit?(y/n?): "; //Asks user if they want to rerun the program? 
    std::cin >> input; //Stores user's answer 

    cout << "\n";

    if (input == 'n' || input == 'N') main(); //Run program again

    else return 0; //Exit Program
}

//*************************************************************
// Definition of function sortArray.                           *
// This function performs an ascending order selection sort on *
// array. size is the number of elements in the array.         *
//**************************************************************

void sortArray(string names[], int size)
{
    int startScan, minIndex;
    string minValue;

    for (startScan = 0; startScan < (size - 1); startScan++)
    {
        minIndex = startScan;
        minValue = names[startScan];

        for (int index = startScan + 1; index < size; index++)
        {
            if (names[index] < minValue)
            {
                minValue = names[index];
                minIndex = index;
            }
        }

        names[minIndex] = names[startScan];
        names[startScan] = minValue;
    }
}

//***************************************************************
// The binarySearch function performs a binary search on an     *
// integer array. array, which has a maximum of size elements,  *
// is searched for the number stored in value. If the number is *
// found, its array subscript is returned. Otherwise, -1 is     *
// returned indicating the value was not in the array.          *
//***************************************************************

int binarySearch(string names[], int size, string value)
{
    int first = 0,         //First array element
    last = size - 1,       //Last array element
    middle,                //Mid point of search
    position = -1;         //Position of search value
    bool found = false;    //Flag

    while (!found && first <= last)
    {
        middle = (first + last) / 2;     //Calculate mid point

        if (names[middle] == value)      //If value is found at mid
        {
            found = true;
            position = middle;
        }

        else if (names[middle] > value)  //If value is in lower half
            last = middle - 1;

        else
            first = middle + 1;          //If value is in upper half
        }

    return position;
}
```

Comment: Where is the loop?

Comment: Are the variable globals? Or are they declared in main()? If they're declared in main() they will just reassign themselves and you don't have to worry about it.

Comment: if/else is not a loop. Also; it's not well defined to call main yourself - don't do that.

Comment: This is not looping structure, You are using recursion for your main() function by using if-else conditional structure. What you want to do here exactly ?

Comment: oops my mistake on terminology. I will change the statement. I got confused because the result was to rerun the program multiple times like a loop reruns a specific section of code. However, you're correct. It's an if-else statement.

Comment: What happens is when the user says they want to rerun the program again by typing 'y', the program runs, but doesn't clear the variables the user manually set values to.

Comment: What do you mean by "clear the variables"? Do you want to reset them to some default value? And also, which variables are we talking about here?

Comment: As an aside, your last `cout <<` statement is missing the `std::` before it.

Comment: The variable that doesn't clear itself when the program reruns is empName which is a stored string type variable the user supplies for the search function. The result is the program does not allow the user to input the string and continues on reproducing the same result over and over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your program is ill-formed; a program should not call `main()`.

> [**basic.start.main/3**](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.start.main#3) The function `main` shall not be used within a program...

Comment: what should I have under the if statement? You don't have to give the exact answer, just point me in the right direction.

Comment: Have an actual loop: surround the logic you want to repeat with `for(;;) { /* repeating logic goes here */ }`. When the user indicates they want to quit, use `break` statement to get out of the loop. For details, see your favorite C++ textbook - that's really C++ 101 stuff.